# Проект Эйлера, 12 задача. Программа выводит пустой результат после того как число делителей превышает 90

Tags: python

Всем привет. Пытаюсь решить 12 задачу из Проекта Эйлера  https://projecteuler.net/problem=12.
Ожидается, что программа выведет `triangle`, как только количество `count` его делителей достигнет определенного значения. Написал такой код:

```
triangle = 0
c = 1
count = 0

while count < 91:
    count = 0
    triangle += c
    c += 1
    for i in range(1, triangle + 1):
        if triangle % i == 0:
            count += 1
    if count == 90:
        print(triangle)
        break
```

Пока `count` меньше 91 результат выводится корректно, когда `count` становится равным 91 или большему числу, то программа работает, но не выводит `triangle`. В чем заключается проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код работает правильно, и проблема вероятнее всего в том, что количество вычислений очень велико, поэтому после 90 делителей ваша программа либо падает, либо решает очень долго.
Попробуйте погуглить оптимальные решения задачи по нахождению количества делителей, они помогут вам сократить количество вычислений. Я предлагаю вам такую оптимизацию: не проверять делимость после `triangle/2`, так как известно, что `x` после `x/2` натуральных делителей иметь не может. Так вы сокращаете количество вычислений вдвое. На 500 не пробовал, попробовал на 200, через две минуты решилось.

```
DIVIDERS_COUNT = 200 # количество делителей искомого числа

triangle = 0 #треугольные числа
c = 1 # переменная для натуральных чисел
count = 1 # счетчик количества делителей


while count < DIVIDERS_COUNT:
    count = 1 # счетчику сразу присваивается 1, так как мы не будем считать triangle
    triangle += c
    for i in range(1, int(triangle/2) + 1 ):
        if triangle % i == 0:
            count += 1
    c += 1
print(triangle)
```

Comment: Даже при сокращении количества делителей путем установки области делителей `range(1, int(triangle\2) + 1)` проблема не ушла В МОЕМ коде. В моем коде все равно при `count = 91` результат пустой. В ВАШЕМ коде все в порядке, результат выводит число

Comment: Отправьте пожалуйста ваш код после исправления, возможно я смогу увидеть ошибку.